# "Where did you fly in from"

Tags: idiomatic-language

Let's say I'm a taxi driver, who often pick up customers outside an airport, would "so, where did you fly in from?" be the more natural way to ask them where they have arrived from?

Answer (score 1):

If you're picking up from an airport, it works perfectly, yes. There may be some that don't want to share the information, so be prepared for that. Otherwise, perfectly reasonable and understandable.